# Rails attributes not being assigned properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a CRUD application where you can create pizzas. You can choose the base, the size and the toppings with `select` elements. For this I used `collection_select`.

However, when a pizza is created, these attributes are not assigned to the new object.

This is my form:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :size_id %><br>
  <%= collection_select(:size, :pizza_id, Size.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :crust_id %><br>
  <%= collection_select(:crust, :pizza_id, Crust.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :toppings %><br>
  <%= collection_select(:toppings, :pizza_id, Topping.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true }) %>
</div>
```

The controller, generated with `scaffold`:

```
class PizzasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pizza, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  ...
  def create
    @pizza = Pizza.new(pizza_params)
    ...
  end
  ...
  private
    def pizza_params
      params.require(:pizza).permit(:name, :price, :size, :crust, :topping => [])
    end
end
```

When I look at the parameters in the log, I can see this:

Processing by PizzasController#create as HTML

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5oiP9EzpTC1fOVGSxv6MXF1qg786Vy3BtnIzEmCh19s=", "pizza"=>{"name"=>"Small pizza", "price"=>"10"}, "crust"=>{"pizza_id"=>"1"}, "toppings"=>{"pizza_id"=>["", "1", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Create Pizza"}
```

It looks like the attributes that are not being saved are not included in the `pizza` key, that's why they are not being assigned to the object.

I noticed the format of the input's `name` should be `pizza[attribute]` so it goes to the correct hash. So I tried something like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:size, :pizza_id, Size.all, :id, :name) %>
```

These are the parameters:

```
Processing by PizzasController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5oiP9EzpTC1fOVGSxv6MXF1qg786Vy3BtnIzEmCh19s=", "pizza"=>{"name"=>"Small pizza", "price"=>"10", "size"=>"1"}, "crust"=>{"pizza_id"=>"1"}, "toppings"=>{"pizza_id"=>["", "1", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Create Pizza"}
```

It doesn't work because it is not transforming the size into the proper class.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're bit incorrect with params order. It should look like

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :size_id %><br>
  <%= collection_select(:pizza, :size_id, Size.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :crust_id %><br>
  <%= collection_select(:pizza, :crust_id, Crust.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :toppings %><br>
  <%= collection_select(:pizza, :topping_ids, Topping.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true }) %>
</div>
```

first parameter is hash root and then attribute

and change params method to be

```
def pizza_params
  params.require(:pizza).permit(:name, :price, :size_id, :crust_id, :topping_ids)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want all the keys included in the pizza key. This is what you need to do:

```
<%= collection_select(:pizza, :crust_id, Crust.all, :id, :name) %>
<%= collection_select(:pizza, :topping_ids, Topping.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true }) %>
```

If you look at the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) for `collection_select`, it states that the first parameter is the key(which is pizza in your case) and the next parameter is the attribute name in the select box(crust/toppings)